# Retrieving WorkOrder records via REST based on Status

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration

I want to fetch all `WorkOrder` records with Status = `In Progress`. I tried using the Query REST resource similar to `/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account` . When I query `WorkOrder` object, it tells me that this object `is not a supported sobject for this request`

Do we have any standard endpoint to achieve this? I don't want to go for a custom webservice solution

Comment: Are you getting an error when running queries against `WorkOrder`? SOQL does work against this object.

Comment: Yes I am getting the error sobject type `WorkOrder` is not supported

Comment: Does SOQL against this object work for you elsewhere? Are you sure you have FSL enabled?

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson . Your questions made me realize the issue was with the version number in the endpoint. I was using v20 in the endpoint URL. For which it is not supported. I am now using v44.0, which works fine now. Thanks again :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson: Do you want to post an answer for this? I'll mark it as resolved

Comment: yes please post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved now. I was using an older API version. The version number should be latest one where the Workorder object is supported. I used `v44.0` and it worked fine